# How to get live log from the long command running in 'docker exec'

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins-pipeline

Using jenkins pipeline I create a docker

```
def res = sh(returnStdout:true, script:
"""#!/bin/bash -lx
    sudo docker run -td --name some_name --network=host -v /usr/src:/usr/src
""")
println res
```

and then I want to run a very-long-command and see its output in live.
Currently I run the command in this way:

```
def res = sh(returnStdout:true, script:
"""#!/bin/bash -lx
    sudo docker exec -t some_name bash -ci "very-long-command"
""")
println res
```

After the very-long-command finished, I print its output.

The problem is that sometimes the very-long-command gets stuck, and the jenkins job aborted due to timeout. In this case I don't have the output at all.

Is it possible to have the live output from docker exec?

Comment: Why are you keeping the results as variable? What happens if you just us use sh()?

Comment: You can run the command as the container's main process, `docker run imagename very-long-command`, and then either the `docker run` output or `docker logs` will have it as normal.  Also consider the Jenkins [`docker.inside()`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#building-containers) method to use ordinary Jenkins `sh('very-long-command')` in the container context.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I cannot use `docker run` for this, because the docker already running and I only `exec` the commands on it. This docker should run some commands

Comment: @Shmuel you are right. This solve the issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

if you know your code is working and, and an idea of how long the build step takes to complete, you can use the `timeout` step in your Jenkins Pipeline job,

More information at the following webpage,
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#timeout-enforce-time-limit